# Определения являются неоднородными,  - не могу понять формулировку этого правила

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, пунктуация

Никак не могу понять это правило. а именно;

***> Определения являются неоднородными,

> если предшествующее определение
> относится не непосредственно к
> определяемому существительному, а к
> сочетанию последующего определения с
> этим существительным:***

Алёша подал ему маленькое складное кругленькое зеркальце (Дост.) (ср.: кругленькое зеркальце — складное кругленькое зеркальце — маленькое складное кругленькое зеркальце); Старуха мать раскладывала виноград на низеньком круглом татарском столике (Л.Т.); …Представляете ли вы себе скверный южный уездный городишко? (Купр.); Ранняя суровая зимняя заря проступала сквозь мертвенную дымку (Ф.).

Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то, чтобы выявлять неоднородность, достаточно критерия "характеризуют предмет с разных сторон".

Но и приведенную формулировку можно объяснить. Для этого надо заглянуть в раздел "Порядок слов в предложении". Там написано:

- определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными, стоят впереди определений, выраженных **относительными** прилагательными (последние, как **выражающие более существенный или постоянный признак**, стоят ближе к определяемому существительному), например: новый исторический роман, поздняя осенняя пора;
- если неоднородные определения выражены только **качественными** прилагательными, то ближе к определяемому существительному ставится то из них, которое **обозначает более устойчивый признак**, например: огромные черные глаза, приятный легкий ветерок;
- если неоднородные определения выражены только **относительными** прилагательными, то обычно они располагаются в порядке восходящей смысловой градации (**от более узкого понятия к более широкому**), например: ежедневные метеорологические сводки, антикварные бронзовые изделия.

Таким образом, неоднородные определения всегда располагаются по схеме "временное/несущественное/узкое" + "постоянное/существенное/широкое". Второй компонент схемы теснее связан с определяемым существительным и образует с ним более прочное единство.

*Скверный южный уездный городишко*: уездный городишко (тип города: маленький, провинциальный) - южный + уездный городишко (этот провинциальный город расположен на юге) - скверный + южный уездный городишко (этот провинциальный городишко, расположенный на юге, не нравится автору).

Однородные определения в равной мере относятся к определяемому существительному. Сравните: *скверный провинциальный городишко* (провинциальный городишко, который мне не нравится, но не все провинциальные города такие, есть и хорошие) и *скверный, провинциальный городишко* (городишко мне не нравится, потому что он провинциальный, он провинциальный, а значит, скверный, все они такие). Почувствуйте разницу: *мне не нравится этот провинциальный город* и *провинциальный город = скверный город*.

Answer (score 2):

Не отрицая ничего из сказанного, добавлю, что однородными могут быть и сочетания относительного и качественного прилагательных, если создается целостное впечатление о предмете. "Мы въехали в новый, большой, кирпичный, современный дом".  У Розенталя: *"Однородные определения могут характеризовать предмет также с разных сторон, если в условиях контекста они объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, причинной связью и т. д.), например: В небе таяло маленькое, золотистое облачко (Горький) (внешний вид); ...Вода струится по камешкам и прядет нитчатые, изумрудно-зеленые водоросли (Солоухин) (общее внешнее впечатление); **весенний, утренний, тоненький** ледок (Твардовский) (общий признак — «слабый, хрупкий»); красные, воспаленные веки («красные, потому что воспаленные»); лунная, ясная ночь («лунная, а потому ясная»)".*

Со времен обучения в университете (а у нас был сильный синтаксист, автор статей в "Грамматике 80") запомнила на всю жизнью, что в трудных случаях различения однородных -неоднородных определений главным критерием является интонация.Т.е.  одни и те же определения могут быть как однородными, так и неоднородными. И ошибки пунктуационной здесь быть не может. Не случайно и в КИМах ЕГЭ такие случаи отсутствуют, так как допускают часто двоякое толкование.

Comment: Вы правы, во всех приведенных примерах имеет место сближение неоднородных признаков в данном тексте (не сходные, а сближенные признаки). Этот прием и следует считать раскрытием ОБЩЕЙ ТЕМЫ. Интересно отметить, что при сближении относ. и качеств. прилагательных часто делается инверсия: относит. прилагательное ставится перед качественным, что видно из приведенных примеров. А вот у Горького  инверсии нет (цвет и размер не переставлены местами), но вариант однородных определений можно считать с общей интонации предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Информация, которую приводит  tat, полезна составителям текста. Кстати, наши классики, видно, с правилами не очень знакомы. По правилам надо написать: "Алёша подал ему маленькое кругленькое складное зеркальце" (Дост.) Также неясно, что значит "ранняя зимняя заря" у Фадеева, это летние зори называют ранними, например: "ранняя заря 18-го августа застала их в боевом порядке", "загорается ранняя заря, а с ней опять майская жизнь".

Что касается решения для имеющегося текста, то можно предложить более простой и понятный вариант.

ПРАВИЛО

1)Сначала определения делятся на качественные и относительные, между собой они всегда неоднородны (порядок расположения: кач. прил. + относит. прил. + сущ.). Относительные прилагательные между собой также неоднородны.

2)Определяется однородность/неоднородность только для  КАЧЕСТВЕННЫХ прилагательных (раскрывают одну тему или обозначают разные признаки).

3) Правильность решения проверяется интонацией (наличие перечислительной интонации для однор. прилагательных).

РЕШЕНИЕ

Маленькое складное кругленькое зеркальце. 1)Относ. прил. "складное". 2) качеств.  прил. "маленькое и кругленькое" обозначают разные признаки. Вывод: все прилагательные неоднородны.

На низеньком круглом татарском столике. Решение аналогичное: два неоднор. качеств. прилаг. и относит. прилаг."татарский".

Скверный южный уездный городишко. Два относит. прилаг. "южный и уездный" и одно качеств. "скверный".Вывод: все прилагательные неоднородны.

Ранняя суровая зимняя заря. Одно качеств. прилагат. "суровая". Следовательно, все прилагательные неоднородны.

Comment: Качественные и относительные прилагательные могут быть однородными, если в условиях контекста между ними создаются синонимические отношения: Холодный, металлический свет блеснул на тысячах мокрых листьев (Гран.). Вы и сами приводили подобный пример: большая, квадратная (= необычная) конфета. Получается, ваш алгоритм дает сбои. Потому Розенталь и предлагает несколько критериев: присоединение определения к словосочетанию, разноплановость признаков и качественность/относительность.

Comment: У Достоевского зеркальце маленькое, видимо, потому что складное, отдалять эти слова друг от друга нельзя. Я бы написала скорее так: Алёша подал ему маленькое, складное кругленькое зеркальце. Но сам-то автор запятую не поставил...

Comment: Один из синонимов "раннего" - "утренний". Фадеев мог иметь в виду утреннюю зарю.

Comment: Прошу прощения, невнимательно прочитала комментарий, и по сути повторила его в своем ответе. Хотела удалить, но уже и к моему ответу появился комментарий.

Comment: Я тоже, как и Ларf, невнимательно не прочитала комментарий. (Кстати, интересно было сравнить общую тональность двух сообщений с похожим содержанием). Впрочем,  основная задача этого комментария - это доказать что алгоритм дает сбой. И за Достоевского домыслить, и Фадеева отстоять. Ну ничем я не могу вас, tat, порадовать и сообщить нечто новое, чего бы вы еще не знали.  Кстати, "металлический" в данном тексте - это уже не относительное, а качественное прилагательное.